Why does Selenium throw an "Exec format error"?
This code throws an exception:
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
time.sleep(10)

Here's the backtrace:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/orangepi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 134, in run
    completed_proc = subprocess.run(args, capture_output=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 503, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1863, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/orangepi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/orangepi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
  File "/home/orangepi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 103, in driver_location
    output = self.run(args)
  File "/home/orangepi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 140, in run
    raise WebDriverException(f"Unsuccessful command executed: {command}") from err
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unsuccessful command executed: /home/orangepi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager --browser chrome --output json


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/orangepi/Downloads/from selenium import webdriver.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/home/orangepi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/orangepi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
  File "/home/orangepi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 41, in get_path
    raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location

I don't know where I am going wrong with this: chrome is installed; I tried a few tutorials and no success.

Did you visit the given link?

BTW, just to look at the initial error, search for "OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error".

The error was due to me using webdriver.Chrome() which looks for webdriver for Chrome. The OS I am using runs on ARM64 and can only use Chromium. Source.
To use Chromium, you need to use the webdriver manager.

Selenium search for chrome driver in your path variables, you can add it manually or set the driver in your code.

This issue can generally be fixed easly by downloading chromium driver https://developer.chrome.com/docs/chromedriver/downloads?hl=fr
Then you can specify the path of this driver in the code or in your env var
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')

Final code :
from selenium import webdriver

# Optional argument : if not specified WebDriver will search your system PATH environment variable for locating the chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
driver.quit()


not the answer for me, but would apply for anyone not using arm64
found mine anyway
